# How to set coordinates for components?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm a new user on Swing, and I have problem with drawing components by coordinates. Please, look at this code:

```
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 700, 600));
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel graph=new JPanel();
    graph.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 700, 300));
    graph.setBackground(Color.white);
    graph.setOpaque(true);
    frame.getContentPane().add(graph);
```

I need that JPanel closes 50% from JFrame, but now it closes 100%, and JFrame has white color for background. How should I fix the mistake? Also, is there any mean for setting width and height using percents? For example, 50% for width. Or may be exists any containers for my question? Thank you

Comment: the answer to solve layout problems _always_ is to use an appropriate LayoutManager. To find out which is appropriate you have to ... well ... learn all about them, f.i. in the tutorial @mKorbel linked to :-)

Answer (score 5):

don't use `whatever#setBound()`, use [Standard LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), in this case is [GridLayout(2, 0)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) best of ways how to do it, your [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) and its [JPanels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) will be resizable on both directions

Comment: +1 for the info, do suggest to always use frame.setVisible(true); at the end, once done adding components to the container :-)

Comment: Thank you. But if I need to set 30/70 percents for 2 panels - how should I do it?

Comment: then you have to use [GridBagLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8746800/714968) or (modern and custom LayoutManager) [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

Comment: please, give me simple example of how should I use GridBagLayout for it

Comment: @user1166635 read the simple tutorial mKorbel linked to, try to achieve your goal with the info given there and come back if you still have a question :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you really want absolute positioning you could try disabling the default layout manager, as shown in [*Doing Without a Layout Manager*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html). However, most of the time it's best to (depending what your container is intended to show) choose an appropriate layout manager.